# How to get the value of the worker task?

Tags: ruby, resque, sidekiq

I can not understand. How to get the results of the sidekiq or resque worker task?
For example:

```
    class HardWorker
      include Sidekiq::Worker

      def perform(a, b)
        a+b
      end
    end



HardWorker.perform_async(10,10)
```

How to get the result?

Answer (score 0):

It is asynchronous operation, accordingly you can update system inside perform method (update database row or something else) or pass custom callback block or function. Don`t forget about asynchrony, you are working in separate thread.

Comment: This is python+celery example http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html

Comment: how i can do this in ruby ecosystem?

Answer (score 0):

You get the result by modifying a system resource shared between the worker and the rest of the system, like the database or the file system ( or S3 on amazon)